# ASP.NET Core 2.0 deploying application written with the code first approach

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm learning how to write application in ASP.NET Core 2.0. I'm following the "code first approach" where I first create a model of my tables and then add a migration to build the database.

What is still unclear to me is how should I deploy the application to the server. I mean, I'm able to publish it to a folder and add it to the IIS on the remote machine.

But what about the database? 
In details:

- should I re-build the database on the server or I have to manually copy the one on the development machine?
- what are the requisites for the server? I have to install any specific driver?

My connection string is:

```
"Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=HelloWorld;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

and I'm using Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: You must create new empty database on your server, that's all what you need. Connection string will be the same, except Database name, and credentials for SQL server.

Comment: Why the name cannot be the same?

Comment: Of course it can, why not.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your previous comment. You might make it as an answer if you want.

Comment: Could you please describe your server and project a bit more?